# android-SQLCipher -Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

I used to have a database and there was no error , My database comes from the asset folder , it's already coded with SQLCipher

after that ,in all of my activities I get this error that the cursor or database is open and didn't closed .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDb.open();
    cursor = myDb.getFavorits();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    myDb.close();
    cursor.close();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
        myDb.close();
        cursor.close();
}
```

this is DBAdapter class where it opens and closes :

```
public void open() {
    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
    File databaseFile = context.getDatabasePath("mydb");
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile,"mypass", null);

    }
public void close() {
    Log.v("this","dbclose");
    db.close(); 
}

public Cursor getFavorits() {
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, null, null, null, null,null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }

    return c;
}
```

but when I leave this activity , it shows me this errors :

```
 Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/pachagename/databases/mydb, table = null, query = SELECT _id from favorits
07-06 15:42:42.769: E/Cursor(1214): net.sqlcipher.database.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

could you help me to find out and solve this problem ?

**Update :**
Something new I notice now , when I enter the activity and without leaving the activity ,it shows me this error !! what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

`onDestroy` is called after `onStop`. I believe you are trying to close something that is already closed. Try to leave only the `super.onDestroy();` in your onDestroy method

EDIT: Just a shot in the dark:

What happens when you change `getFavorits()` to `private static method` and call it from onCreate like this: `cursor = DBAdapter.getFavorits()` ?

Comment: it's not closed otherwise it shouldn't show me this error . by the way , I try what you said , didn't work

Comment: Given your new info i guess onStop and onDestroy is not the problem (at least yet). Please post the code of `getFavorits()` method. The problem probably lies there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that you are closing the database before closing the Cursor. The Cursor should be closed before the database as the cursor accesses the database.